# Cannot find an asset bundle containing the path "~/Public/stylesheets/main.less"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cassette

I've tried accessing Cassette's debugging page to see what's what, but all I get is a blank page (**Firebug says I'm receiving a 404 header**). Don't really know why:

```
www.foobar.com/_cassette
               ^-----------This is the debugger page for Cassette.
```

I'm using ASP.Net MVC3 with Cassette for asset bundling and minification.

Everything is working correctly on my dev machine, but when deploying to the hosting server, this is the message I receive:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Cannot find an asset bundle
>   containing the path "~/Public/stylesheets/main.less".
>
> Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Cannot find an asset
>   bundle containing the path "~/Public/stylesheets/main.less".

Again: Everything works correctly on my dev machine.

Here is my CassetteConfiguration file:

```
public void Configure(BundleCollection bundles, CassetteSettings settings)
{    
    bundles.Add<StylesheetBundle>("~/Public/stylesheets");
    bundles.Add<ScriptBundle>("~/Public/javascripts");
}
```

And in my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
@{
    Bundles.Reference("~/Public/stylesheets/bootstrap.css");
    Bundles.Reference("~/Public/stylesheets/main.less");
}
```

I'm using a Shared "Cloud" hosting from Vidahost.

What steps can I take to debug this problem? I've been working on it all afternoon and so far haven't broken new ground.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'm having exactly the same problem

Comment: @ipr101: This problem only happens when hosting the app on Vidahost (a shared hosting environment). I imagine this has something to do with folder writing permissions, since the _cassette folder is create on the fly. Unfortunately I have not found a solution, I just switched to my own VPN server to avoid these issues.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. I've been having the same problems with a website running on discount.asp which I suspect maybe due to similar issues. I think I'll just stop using 'cassette' in the solution for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below in BundleConfig file

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-1.*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css");
        }
```